# Where i can find the github installed apps?

Tags: software-installation, git

So i installed some github apps, by :

```
git clone git://github.com/xxxxx.git
cd [app's dir on my /home]
sudo make install
```

And now i need to remove it, should i remove that first directory? Or there's another place?
Where to find him?

Comment: Most well behaved applications will support `sudo make uninstall` when run from the source directory. Did you try that?

Comment: `No rule to make target 'uninstall'. Stop. `It doesn't support that.

Comment: @QIS                                    
still there?? any help?

Comment: It's too late for this install, but use [GNU stow](http://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) or [CheckInstall](http://checkinstall.izto.org/) or similar tool when installing software from source in future.   They provide ways to manage (including uninstall) such software, even if they don't provide an `uninstall` make target.

Comment: For this program, you could try running `make -n install` (i.e. a dry-run) to see what it did when you ran `make install`.  Then you could use that to help you manually undo whatever it did.

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation, some packages have a `make uninstall` (or similar) target. If not, you'd have to find out where (and what) files got installed (most likely under `/usr/local` by default) and delete them by hand. If some file got overwritten by the installation, you are out of luck... A way to find out what was installed is to repeat the installation, saving (verbose) output to a file and work from there.

Learn how to create your own packages from source, if you install self-knit packages, your package manager will do clean uninstall for you.